# Using functions in 'while' loop python

Tags: python, function, edx

So I want to create a code that would calculate the minimum monthly payment and remaining balance, given an annual interest rate, principal amount and monthly payment rate. The desired output is:

```
      Month: 1
      Minimum monthly payment: 168.52
      Remaining balance: 4111.89
      Month: 2
      Minimum monthly payment: 164.48
      Remaining balance: 4013.2
```

and so on until month 12.

I know there's a way to do it without defining functions but the whole function thing was just messing me up so I wanted to try it. My current code is -

```
        a=0
        while a<=11:
            def min_mth_pay(balance,monthlyPaymentRate):
                x = balance * monthlyPaymentRate
                return x
            def balance(balance,min_mth_pay,annualInterestRate):
                y=(balance - min_mth_pay)*((annualInterestRate/12)+1)
                return y
            a +=1
            print('Month:' + str(a) + 'Minimum monthly payment:' + str(x) + 'Remaining balance:' + str('y'))
```

I'm not even sure if I can use functions in such a format? The error pops out saying the name 'x' is undefined. Really new at Python here obviously would appreciate any clarifications! :)

Comment: The learning process is first studying the concept, understanding it, thinking of applications and then trying to use them. You skipped to the last step immediately .

Comment: May I ask what's the reason for defining a function inside a loop?

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing *defining* functions with *calling* them. You should define then functions separately, then call them from within your loop.

```
def min_mth_pay(balance,monthlyPaymentRate):
    x = balance * monthlyPaymentRate
    return x

def balance(balance,min_mth_pay,annualInterestRate):
    y=(balance - min_mth_pay)*((annualInterestRate/12)+1)
    return y


a=0
while a<=11:
    a +=1
    x = min_mth_pay(balance,monthlyPaymentRate)
    y = balance(balance,min_mth_pay,annualInterestRate)

    print('Month:' + str(a) + 'Minimum monthly payment:' + str(x) + 'Remaining balance:' + str(y))
```

Note that it's not clear where balance, monthlyPaymentRate, min_mth_pay, and annualInterestRate are coming from in your code.

Comment: You failed to address the issue that `balance` appears to be both the name of a variable and of a function...